# Weird stuffs in smoke + fire sim

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation, fire, mantaflow

So, i've been messing around with this project for a solid total of 10+ hours. And i still can't figure out why the fire is so weird. It has this bobbly blocky thing even in "decent" resolution at one point (256).
How do i terminate this issue? Any help/tips are truly appreciated!
oh yeah, here's my settings, im in b2.92
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simulation is set for smoke and fire, and for whatever reason the smoke is occluding most of the inner flame, making the voxel nature of the simulation very obvious. I recommend you set it to fire only, and only use the flame smoke, or possibly make the smoke not as dense (in the material settings).

Comment: Thanks, that helps! But what do I do if I wanted a thick smoke, since I wanted this simulation to look like a legit flamethrower like the iridesium's version but, I wanted to integrate this fire sim to a video. If I do fire only, it wouldn't look legit since the video background is visible even at the back of the fire sim.